# Coloring backgorund of richtextbox line in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I'm trying to color a specific line's background in a RichTextBox.
I need the line's background to be colored all the way to the end of the right side of the control.
I tried using the SelectionBackColor property, but it colors only until the end of the line.
Does anybody know of a way to do this?
thanks :)

Comment: Did you find a way to do this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mmm, I believe you cannot do it without some custom painting, because as you said, with RTF formatting you format text so if you do not have text ( chars or white spaces or tabs... ) you cannot reach those parts of the control which are completely empty, unless you do change the whole control background color...

Answer (score 0):

Bit messy, but if you don't want to go ahead with custom painting the control. You could make the textbox transparent, then add an image behind the control which has the line selected. You could then change the Image.Location.Y value on the TextChanged event.

Answer (score 0):

Customizing the stock Windows rich text control is possible, but they didn't make it easy. If I were you, I would do what I did: [Purchase a better text control](http://www.actiprosoftware.com/products/dotnet/windowsforms/syntaxeditor/default.aspx).